# Bundle with both CDN and local Resources in CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, cdn, bundling-and-minification

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Resources/styles/css").Include(
                      "~/Resources/styles/bootstrap-3.1.1.css",
                      "~/Resources/third-party/ng-table.css",
                      "~/Resources/styles/site.css"));
```

I have above kind of bundle in my 'BundleConfig.cs' file.How can I add cdn into above bundle ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

My CDN is :

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```